# AAD B2C Multiapps Authenication and Authorisation concerns

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We're looking into Azure AAD B2C since we offer bespoke applications to a number of users. We've chosen B2C since we're after 1 user repository but these users can span across a number of domain applications

It's my understanding that AAD B2C is just a IdP and isn't concerned about user claims.

I am confused though, since we're supporting N number of applications with this single B2C instance, where does Authorisation sit?

With the app? If so, I assume my users will authenticate with AAD, get a token, and then use the said token to call an API / APP? Won't each request require a round trip to the database to see if said UID (User Id) can do said action?

Some of these domain apps could be SPA's, others could be API;s others could be simple MVC applications

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rest api request during authentication to fetch an attribute containing the users roles. Then the app/api can just examine that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment?pivots=b2c-custom-policy